# Is using past participle instead of present one more polite?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, past-participles, present-participles

On [christianity.stackexchange.com I asked this question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/8050/is-it-true-that-john-paul-the-second-restored-the-practice-of-selling-indulgence?noredirect=1#comment38076_8050):

"Is it true that John Paul the Second restored the practice of **selling** indulgences in 2000?"

and one supporter suggested that I replace **selling** with **sold** as in this way it will sound less accusatory.

While not being a native English speaker and at the same not doubting a bit about that supporter's command of English, I am still puzzled here about how changing the tense of the verb can make things sound less accusatory. In fact, I don't quite see how the question is accusatory in the first place. Perhaps, there is some subtlety in English grammar here that I am not aware about.

Can anyone, please, explain this to me?

Comment: Whoever said that "Is it true that John Paul the Second restored the practice of **sold indulgences** in 2000?" is more polite & less accusatory was ignorant of English grammar. This sentence is ungrammatical. It replaces a noun ("selling" =  gerund) with an adjective ("sold" = past participle). The only way to make your sentence less accusatory is to turn it into a passive: "Is it true that the Catholic Church's long-outlawed practice of selling indulgences was restored in 2000?" The lack of an agent makes it strictly a Q rather than an implicit accusation of the late Pope.

Comment: @BillFranke - "No agent makes it strictly a Q" - What do you mean by an agent here?

Comment: I mean that the passive sentence doesn't say who might have restored the practice of selling indulgences, but your sentence asks whether or not it was the Pope (the agent; the actor; the person who restored the practice). Passive voice is used when the agent (the person or thing that did it) is unimportant or when the speaker doesn't want to admit responsibility (e.g., "**Mistakes were made**" doesn't say who made the mistakes, so it has no agent, but it would if it said "Mistakes were made **by me**") instead of "**I made** mistakes" ("**I**" is the agent, the maker of the mistakes).

Comment: @BillFranke: Why would sold be ungrammatical? It would just be an awkward sentence (and a different construction): *not the practice of indulgences **given out for free**, but the practice of **sold** indulgences*. I agree that *selling* is much better, but *sold* is perhaps not impossible. I can also see how it might be slightly less accusatory, as it links the Pope in a less direct way to the selling of indulgences; with *selling*, he might seem to be more involved in the practice of selling.

Comment: @Cerberus: Ungrammatical because the practice is "selling indulgences", which is a verbal (gerund) noun phrase & the OBJ of the prep **of**. There is no "practice of indulgences". It's not idiomatic &, IMHO, wouldn't be said by a native Anglophone. But I'm willing to be overruled. Making the Pope the agent (he "restored the practice", whatever the name) is no less accusatory with _sold_ than with _selling_: the Pope restored the practice, so he's the responsible (guilty) party. This is a matter of semantics, not grammatical structure. What does the sentence mean? The same thing in both forms.

Comment: @Bill: I agreed with everything you've said until you spoilt it with that last line.  *The practice of selling indulgences* is grammatical and meaningful; it could be seen as accusatory. *The practice of sold indulgences* is not grammatical. It might mean the same as the original: it might mean the use of indulgences that have been previously sold; it might mean forgiveness for the past sin of selling indulgences. "OK, it's a mistake but you know what I meant" is not only arrogant but wrong; the reason for correct grammar is precisely so that listeners can know your meaning.

Comment: @Tim: I agree with your last sentence. I think that the person who told the OP to use "sold" isn't a native Anglophone & doesn't understand the difference between saying "Would you please shut the door?" & "Will you please shut the door?" (the first is slightly more polite) & using a real past participle ("sold", & Prof Lawler recently pointed out that "would/could/should" aren't past tense forms or past participles) instead of a gerund ("selling"). My point was just that keeping the Pope as the agent of "restored" keeps him responsible for something, even if we don't what it is.

Comment: @BillFranke: You said "ungrammatical". I said "grammatical, but awkward".

Comment: @Cerberus: I also said that I'm willing to be overruled on the charge of "ungrammatical", which means that this isn't really an important question for me. More important is whether it's idiomatic. The lack of idiomaticity & semantic precision (ambiguity) make it unacceptable to me. I don't think it's awkward as much as it's unclear because, as Tim Lymington points out, it's ambiguous & even [multibiguous](http://snurl.com/26tpqu6)(p 141).

Comment: I agree with @Cerberus on this one. Except I don't think *sold indulgences* is seriously "awkward" (here's an example of the [practice of exchanged visits](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22practice+of+exchanged+visits+%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) which I think is structurally similar and perfectly okay). And I certainly agree with OP's advisor that ***sold*** is less "accusatory", in that it links the action more to the *things sold* rather than the *people selling them*. This is a *very* fine nuance, but one which a [very] competent native speaker might well make.

Comment: properly phrased, *indulgentiae vendendae* will be more indirect than *vendere indulgentias* in ecclesiastical latin

Answer (score 3):

I posted as much in a comment, but on reflection I think it should be presented as a voteable answer, since differing opinions are being expressed.

Personally, I don't find *sold indulgences* seriously "awkward". It's a somewhat less common form, but to my ear it implies the speaker/writer is actually *more* precise than the average person who might have just used *selling*, and has chosen his words with great care. Similar usages include...

> 1: The proceeds of indulgences, first in the form of vow redemption payments and later in that of [sold indulgences](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22policy%20of%20taxed%20food%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22sold%20indulgences%20were%22&oq=%22sold%20indulgences%20were%22&gs_l=serp.3...2464.2464.3.2669.1.1.0.0.0.0.38.38.1.1.0...0.0...1c.1.16.psy-ab.qNY7AOuvo7M&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.47534661,d.d2k&fp=575db4e7c24bc40c&biw=1292&bih=930), were undoubtedly more substantial.
>   2: There is an ongoing [practice of exchanged visits](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22practice%20of%20exchanged%20visits%20%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) between the Fez families and their African friends.
>    3: They also demanded that the [practice of unpaid labour](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22practice%20of%20unpaid%20labour%20for%20the%20chief%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) for the chief be-scrapped.
>    4: The Panama Canal would not call for any change in our [policy of untaxed navigation](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22the%20Panama%20Canal%20would%20not%20call%20for%20any%20change%20in%20our%20policy%20of%20untaxed%20navigation%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1).
>    5: ...the devastating effects of the [policy of banned abortion](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22policy%20of%20banned%20abortion%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) in Romania under Ceausescu

To paraphrase OP's advisor (and Cerberus's comment), *sold* can indeed be seen as less "accusatory", in that it places more emphasis on the *things sold*, rather than on the *people selling them*. This is a very fine nuance, but one which a competent, careful native speaker might well make.

Comment: I am afraid that, unlike in cases with exchanged visits, unpaid labor, untaxed navigation and banned abortion, "sold indulgences" would imply an irrevocable, once-for-all action. I mean, you can't sell again those indulgences that you've already sold out - you simply don't posses them anymore. You can only sell other, not sold ones. So, I would have a hard time even trying to envision what "the practice of sold indulgences" in fact is. However, the practice of exchanged visits can go on and on as visits can be repeated. Same with practices of taxation, making abortions and labor underpayment.

Comment: Just to give a further thought, "visit", "labor", "navigation" and "abortion" are all nouns describing actions, while "indulgence" is a noun describing a physical thing, not an action.

Comment: @brilliant: The fact that you might not be familiar with the usage, and might have trouble understanding it, isn't really the point. We're not discussing the pros and cons of a hypothetical usage that  OP *might* adopt - we're talking about a usage that *does exist* (albeit not all that common). And as for that "further thought" - all those words have noun forms derived from underlying original verbs, but that's irrelevant. It's the *gerund/past participle* of the other word *(sell, exchange, tax, ban)* that we're looking at.

Comment: "And as for that "further thought" - all those words have noun forms derived from underlying original verbs, but that's irrelevant" - I think it IS relevant because "the practice of" requires a noun (or a noun phrase) denoting an action following right after it. But the noun "indulgence" is not a noun derived from a verb, it doesn't denote an action at all! Thus, "the practice of indulgences" sounds just as awkward as "the practice of houses" or "the practice of tables". "We're not discussing the pros and cons of a hypothetical usage that OP might adopt" - Just in case, I AM the OP.

Comment: Further thought, "the practice of exchanged visits" is fine ("visit" is an action), "the practice of visited house" is not fine ("house" is not an action), "the practice of untaxed navigation" is fine ("navigation" is an action), "the practice of navigated ship" is not fine ("ship" is not an action), "the practice of banned abortion" is fine ("abortion" is an action), "the practice of aborted child" is not fine ("child" is not an action).

Comment: @brilliant: Sorry about the "OP" reference - I wasn't paying attention. But okay - you ask whether this usage involves "some subtlety in English grammar". I'm telling you it *does*, and that your advisor - albeit perhaps somewhat "overprecise" - is perfectly correct. Consider [Mr. Chamberlain endeavours to coerce them into a. policy of taxed food](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22policy+of+taxed+food%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) if you don't like earlier examples. *Less accusatory* is subjective, but without question the usage is ***valid***.

Comment: Please, stick to the word "practice" and don't substitute the word "policy" for it. The reason being "the practice of" will require a noun denoting an action in Appositive Genitive (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apposition), but the "the policy of" may not. It is because the word  "practice" itself denotes an action, but the word "policy" may not (it may merely mean "a rule", which is not an action).

Comment: @brilliant: I don't think this discussion is going anywhere. If you think there's some grammatical principle involved here which allows the usage with *policy*, but somehow debars it with *practice*, I'm afraid you're trying to shoehorn English into a coherent logic system that simply doesn't exist. I'm a native speaker, and I'm telling you the usage is valid. If you don't like it, don't feel obliged to use it. But you certainly won't convince me that it's "invalid".

Comment: A lot of native speakers have told me that it is invalid. How do you yourself picture the practice of sold indulgences in your mind? What can on earth anyone do with an indulgence that he has already sold to someone?! What can you practice there? "involved here which allows the usage with policy, but somehow debars it with practice" - It is always better to stick to the original case as close as possible. You can't deny that there is a difference between "practice" and "policy". Some differences are very subtle, and can't be seen right away, so it's better to avoid them.

Comment: @brilliant: A lot of native speakers aren't all that competent when it comes to relatively uncommon constructions like this. I've added a specific instance of *sold indulgences* if you're still having trouble accepting that the usage can and does occur. I "picture" the expression as meaning *indulgences which are **sold** [as opposed to being "given", with no money changing hands]*. And I understand *the practice of **X*** here as meaning *the performance / execution / operation of an organised / endorsed activity involving **X*** (where *policy* is effectively a synonym).

Comment: "I've added a specific instance of sold indulgences if you're still having trouble accepting that the usage can and does occur" - Where is the word "practice" in that instance? I see "in that of sold indulgences", and "that" is a pronoun for he word "form". So, at best I could read that as "in the form of sold indulgences", which sounds absolutely fine to me. However... once again, where is the word "practice"? My case involves that word. Please, find an example with the word "practice".

Comment: @brilliant: To repeat: "I don't think this discussion is going anywhere". The usage is in fact valid, although it's uncommon / stylised / dated / formal. Which answers the question as originally  posed. You now seem to be twisting it into asking for support for your apparent preconception that it's *not* a valid usage. I can't help you there, because I don't really have the technical skill to search the relevant corpora for instances of *the practice of [past participle] [noun]*. I can only tell you the basic form is valid, and the specific word *practice* isn't really relevant.

Comment: "And I understand the practice of X here as meaning the performance / execution / operation of an organised / endorsed activity involving X" - So how do you imagine an activity involving something that in fact is not there?! Imagine you sold all your indulgences to me yesterday, and now I am far away from you. What kind of activity can you now possibly perform on those indulgences that are in fact in my hands and not with you any more?! I am sorry for being kind of stubborn and dumb here, but I honestly don't understand.

Comment: "The usage is in fact valid ... you now seem to be twisting it into asking for support for your apparent preconception that it's not a valid usage" - In fact, I don't understand what "valid" here means in the first place. What do you mean by "valid" here?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9172/discussion-between-fumblefingers-and-brilliant)

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing inherently accusatory about "selling" vs "sold", but depending on context, it could be seen as a bit too direct for many native speakers' tastes.

For asking a stranger in a public context, I'd say your phrasing could be perceived as confrontational. If it's a rhetorical question in something you're writing, it's perfect. Concise and clear.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a big distinction, but there is a subtle one:

"He restored the practice of selling indulgences..." could be read to imply that the pope was the one actually doing the selling.

"He restored the practice of *sold* indulgences..." seems to distance the pope from the selling somewhat.  The indulgences were sold by someone somewhere, but it doesn't sound like the pope was doing it personally.

To my ears it's a trivial distinction, but I can see where maybe someone might look at it that way.

I find the use of "sold" here to be mildly awkward, but I agree with FumbleFingers that it is fundamentally valid.